# Renistall of Jenkins on Windows

Tags: jenkins

I may need to reinstall Jenkins on a Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise server. If I run the installer for an already installed version, it gives me the option of uninstalling. I've already tried the "repair" option but it didn't solve my problem. If I do the uninstall, what will happen to my existing jobs and their history? Will the entire Jenkins folder be deleted? If so, will I be able to restore them from a backed up copy?

Comment: Are you already on the latest version? Why can't you try upgrading?

Comment: I'm running the latest (1.502), but am considering trying a reinstall to try to resolve an issue. When I installed this version, I was logged in to the server as Administrator, but didn't run the setup as administrator. I wanted to make sure I could retain the jobs and history if I did this.

Comment: Do yourself a favor.  And remove the need for other people in this process.  If there is any chance that you will lose info.  THen back it up.  REinstall Jenkins.  And then let me know, "Does it delete my stuff"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about Windows, but I think in linux, the jobs/configs directory can be copied across multiple Jenkins installations. Make a backup of your jenkins home directory first. The Jenkins executable itself is less critical, as it can easily be reinstalled without affecting your build environment. See this link for more information: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins

Comment: I had tried restoring a deleted job a while back, but had not seen the "restore configuration from disk" step. I have a couple of more things to try before I attempt a reinstall, but it's good to know I should be able to restore all of the jobs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can restore them by backing up your jenkins install folder and then copying the contents back to the jenkins install folder after reinstallation. This works for linux or windows. All job info and configuration is stored on the file system.

Comment: Good to know. I assume the "reload configuration from disk" command must be run after copying the old stuff back in.

Comment: I usually just restart the service, but running the reload config command certainly couldn't hurt.

Comment: As it turns out, using the setup to uninstall left the jobs folder intact, so I didn't have to do anything after reinstalling.